# Qiskit: Understanding statevector output

Tags: qiskit

I am looking for some help in understanding the state vector output.
I am studying myself and found some exercise online. Below question is from one of those exercises -
Given two qubits. Both of them are in 0 state. Using the single-qubit gates, turn them into |+> state and |-> state respectively.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, assemble, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister

qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.h(0)
qc.measure(0, 0) 

qc.x(1)
qc.h(1)
qc.measure(1, 1)
qc.draw(output="mpl")
```

[image: circuit]

```
svsim = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
qc.save_statevector()
qobj = assemble(qc)
final_state = svsim.run(qobj).result().get_statevector(decimals=3)

from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(final_state, prefix="\\text{Statevector} = ")
```

Output: Statevector=[0 0 −1 0]

Upon plotting on bloch sphere, I get below -

[image: bloch-sphere]

It is my understanding that state vectors are amplitudes. So, how is qubit0 state is 0 and same for qubit 1.

Thanks!

Comment: You can also try to see if the Bloch sphere has another case once these two quanta are entangled, perhaps .....

Comment: There is no entanglement as they are single qubit gates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is circuit is easy to analyse. H gate on qo will result in a + state. The x gate on q1 puts 1 to 1 state. Next te Hgate on q1 will put q1 in the - state.
In the circuit measurementgates are used and therefore the output will collapse to 1 and -1. Measurement gates are only needed for measuring counts.

from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, assemble, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister

qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.h(0)
#qc.measure(0, 0)

qc.x(1)
qc.h(1)
#qc.measure(1, 1)
qc.draw(output="mpl")

plot_bloch_multivector(final_state)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful to understand. :-)